# Cross compatibility between Jedis and Redisson clients

Tags: caching, serialization, redis, jedis, redisson

We have two applications that use the same redis cache cluster. One of the application (say App1) uses Jedis and the other (say App2) uses Redisson. For now we may assume that both the applications can read and write Java objects into the cache, although we may end up with App2 (with Redisson) alone doing the writes.

My question here is whether objects written by Redisson can be read by Jedis (and vice versa) in terms of serialisation and deserialisation.

I have the following understanding right now regarding both the clients. Looking for a validation of the same and/ or ways to make them compatible.

- Redisson client has APIs to store java objects directly using internal serialisation and deserialisation while Jedis does not.
- Serialisation and deserialisation process may be configurable within Redisson, so we may be able to use the same mechanism in App1 with Jedis.

I am quite sure that this should be possible because Redis being an external cache and distributed system should be agnostic across client libraries in same or different programming languages.

Update: App1 uses RedisTemplate to use Jedis client which is configured with a StringSerializer. Also, Redisson provides a configuration to set a Codec, where Jackson is one of the option. Using Jackson, the value saved in Redis is a json string, with the only caveat that it stores a @class property which fails in deserialisation with Jackson object mapper using Jedis.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringCodec` it's compatible with `StringSerializer`